# Why not to use global varaibles in React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reviewing some React code and the developer has used a module scoped global variable to pass a data across components. In react we typically encourage to use context or global store. What reasons should we specify as part of review comments.

Something I could think of are

1. The global variable becomes a transient dependency and will impact reusability of the components and hence is an anti pattern in react.

Would like to understand any other potential issues in using a module scoped global variable or this is a valid pattern.

Comment: is your global variable a state or simply a variable?

Comment: It's not just a React issue. Generally in any language you will want to avoid "unscoped" global variables.

Comment: @burningalc - the code is currently a variable to hold data to be passed to another component.

Comment: @DrewReese - Great point. It may not scale well as more such variables crops up or global state is maintained.

Comment: "the code is currently a variable to hold data to be passed to another component." sounds like this developer just didn't want to put in the effort and/or time to use the normal established React patterns of global state/Context API (or even routing/navigation) to move data around in the app. I think the biggest concern with a global variable is that there's no control over when and how it's updated, so any bugs with it can be potentially very difficult to diagnose since you won't have the certainty of the React component lifecycle.

Comment: @DrewReese - Agreed